# javamail download only selected attachments from my inbox

Tags: download, jakarta-mail, attachment

I am using javamail for download my gmail attachments to my local system.
I can download all attachments from my inbox.But i want to download only the selected mail's attachments from my inbox.How can i achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

vino

Answer (score 0):

You know that loop where you iterated over all the attachments and saved each one?  Change it to only save the one you want.

Comment: If i select a mail in my inbox,then how can i track the selected mail id from my code.Here i will select one or more mails with attachments.The code is,`Message message[] = folder.getMessages();
        int i,n;       
        for(i = 0; i<message.length; i++){                    
                Object content = message[i].getContent();               
                if (content instanceof Multipart) {
                    handleMultipart((Multipart)content);
                } 
                else {
                    handlePart(message[i]);
                }           
        }`

Comment: What do you mean by "track" and what do you mean by "mail id"?  You've shown a loop to iterate over all the messages in the mailbox.  What else do you want to do?  Write the "handle" methods to do whatever you want with each message.